# Vectors vs arrays (speed)

Tags: c++, arrays

I was wondering which is the fastest for general use. So instead of push_back() we could use the following code for arrays. I thought arrays are faster but I am not sure of that.

```
 int *p;
 p = new int[5];
 for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
    *(p+i)=i;

 // realloc
 int* temp = new int[6];
 std::copy(p, p + 5, temp); 
 delete [] p;
 p = temp;
```

Comment: Put the profiler on it. :)

Comment: Just use std::vector - Already implemented

Comment: In general, a "real" C array will be faster to access than any sort of object.  (But of course rapid access is not the only criterion for choosing a construct.)

Comment: This is exactly what `std::vector` is doing under the hood, only with automatic memory management, exception safety, amortized re-size cost, etc. etc.

Comment: an array will usually be "faster" than a vector, but like the previous comments said, `std::vector` handles everything for you.. the impact to speed should be negligible, not worth worrying about :)

Answer (score 4):

Implementations of `std::vector` are usually optimized for general use.  For any specific case, a native array will be better or equal performance, but if you don't know the exact usage characteristics up front, a vector will usually be decent performance, and better than a native array that hasn't been thought through.  For example, in the code above, you explicitly reallocate the memory, while a vector implementation might have already allocated enough memory (e.g. to make the vector a minimum of one cache line).

Comment: let's not forget that with a good `allocator` an `std::vector` might get really interesting performances with almost 0 effort, especially pool allocators.